# Creating a simple calculator in C using switch-statement

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a beginner at C programming and I just finished making a calculator using if-else statements in my code. And now I tried of doing the same using switch-statement, but it is always executing the default. Please look into my code and suggest me what is going wrong.
I am currently writing the code in CodeBlock.

[image: This is the message i'm getting]

```
int main()
{
    printf("\nWhat operation do you want to do:\n\tA)Addition\n\tB)Subtraction\n\tC)Multiplication\n\tD)Division\n");
    float num1;
    printf("Please enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    float num2;
    printf("Please enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    char myChar;
    scanf("%c", &myChar);
    switch (myChar)
    {
        case 'A':
            printf("The addition of %.2f and %.2f is %.2f", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("The subtraction of %.2f and %.2f is %.2f", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;
        case 'C':
            printf("The multiplication of %.2f and %.2f is %.2f", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;
        case 'D':
            printf("The quotient of %.2f and %.2f is %.2f", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            break;
        default :
            printf("You enterned incorrect input");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `char myChar;
    scanf("%c", &myChar);` move to before `float num1;`

Comment: When you `scanf("%c", &myChar)` you're reading the newline left after reading your second number.  Your `switch()` doesn't have a case for that, so it runs the default.

Comment: If you want to read a line, use code that reads a line, not code that reads a character or a number. For your code to work as shown, you'd have to enter "32 43+<enter>" since your code reads two numbers and a character.

Comment: You caused the error by pushing `<enter>` after the second number even though you have no code to read that. Instead, enter `4+` for the second number. That way, when you code reads a number and then a character, it will get `4` then `+` instead of `4` then `<enter>`.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input; use `fgets`.

Comment: *it fails to execute properly* is an absolutely useless error description unless you explain what *fails to execute properly* means. What **specific problem** are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C scanf() issues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236684/c-scanf-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is mostly related to `scanf` that the remaining `\n` from the previous input was interpreted as the input for the one.

Also your prompt for operation does not match with its corresponding input.

Suggest a fix:

```
float num1;
printf("Please enter the first number: ");
scanf("%f", &num1);

float num2;
printf("Please enter the second number: ");
scanf("%f", &num2);

printf("\nWhat operation do you want to do:\n\tA)Addition\n\tB)Subtraction\n\tC)Multiplication\n\tD)Division\n");
char myChar;
scanf(" %c", &myChar);
```

You can add `printf` as debugging purpose - that would help, too. Example for 1st input:

```
float num1;
printf("Please enter the first number: ");
scanf(" %f", &num1);
printf("num1 = %f\n", num1 );
```

Comment: `" "` is redundant before `"%f"`.

Comment: @melpomene my bad "%f" skips spaces itself..